# Не весь набор кнопок в x code

Tags: xcode, ios

Мужики, выручайте.
В чем проблема, у меня при создании проекта пропадает ряд кнопок в инструментале xcode.
http://s6.uploads.ru/z6Hpm.png

с чем это связано?

Answer (score 1):

все верно, проект под iOS, в нем только одна кнопка, но оформить ее можно как угодно. Остальные кнопки появятся при создании десктопного проекта.

Answer (score 0):

[@tragvar](/users/11201/tragvar), не совсем так, и там, и там внешний вид определяется свойством style, просто в Desktop-приложениях кнопки со всеми стилями вывели в палитру, а в айоси вывели только одну, но в обоих случаях тип можно поменять в ксибе, например, вставить в десктопной версии push и превратить его в градиентную кнопку.

Хотя по факту там все-таки кажется куча разных классов, а `[UIButton buttonWithType:]` - фабрика, но это вопрос реализации и нам все равно виден только основной класс